# O que acontece com um Cronjob de 2:30, se o servidor cair às 2:28 e só voltar 5 minutos depois?

Tags: linux, cron, agendamento

Não sei se a pergunta é confusa, mas é que eu tenho utilizado muito Cronjob em meus sistemas atualmente e não quero ter problemas. Então vou exemplificar minha preocupação com  uma situação hipotética.

Imaginemos que eu tenha um Cronjob programado para rodar `2:30` da manhã. Porém, a provedora do servidor precisou entrar em manutenção (ou deu algum problema interno) e desligou o servidor as `2:28` da manhã. Mas 5 minutos depois, ou seja, `2:32`, o serviço foi restabelecido.

O que vai acontecer com aquele agendamento de  `2:30`?
Será executado quando a máquina iniciar? Ou será completamente ignorado, sendo executado apenas no outro dia?

Eu preciso saber disso, pois tenho alguns scripts que têm datas ou horários específicos para rodar, e não quero ter prejuízos com informações e eventos dos meus sistemas.

Caso a resposta seja **sim** para "será ignorado?", como posso fazer para verificar se o servidor foi reiniciado e se um cron não foi executado em determinado horário e, então, executar?

Comment: Uma duvida que eu sempre tive. +1, também é algo que gostaria de saber em Windows-Server, se existe alguma situação no agendador de tarefas.

Comment: Sim é possível também para Windows Server,o equivalente do Cronjob seria o Task Scheduler. Para mais informações olhe esse link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler

Comment: @Falion acho que não me entendeu, eu quero saber se o problema pode ocorrer no WindowsServer, se ele executa a tarefa mesmo que o tempo tenha passado, por exemplo a maquina ficou desligada 30 minutos e nesse tempo tinha uma tarefa =) basicamente a mesma pergunta do Wallace, mas em windowsserver, obrigado

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Então,o equivalente ao do Windows Server é o Task Scheduler e ele assim como outros segue o mesmo padrão que o Cron do Linux,caso a maquina fique desligada por exemplo 30 minutos e nesse tempo tinha uma tarefa,ele não irá executar,já que assim como outros Cron,ele toma como principio de que o sistema continua 24 horas sem parar.É por isto que é recomendado usar outros serviços a mais além do Cronjob para não ocorrer erros como este.

Comment: Em que linguagem esta trabalhando? se for algo web, pode mostrar como faço deste lado ;)

Comment: @Fábio sim senhor, trabalho com Web. PHP :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simples, ele não será executado pois o *Cronjob* ignora um serviço que passou do horário e em que o sistema não estava a funcionar e só irá executar em um outro dia normalmente(caso não venha a ocorrer a mesma situação).

No Linux, os usuários usam o *Crontab*, mas para melhor performance do sistema agendado também é bom usar um programa chamado *Anacron*.

O *Anacron* é um programa que lhe ajuda a agendar intervalos específicos no dia, assim junto com o Cron você pode fazer com que não tenha mais estes erros de agendamento, já que o Cron assume que o sistema trabalha 24 horas por dia.

**Para saber usar o Cron com o Anacron eu lhe sugiro ler este artigo que explica sobre como usar :**

http://www.tuxradar.com/content/automate-linux-cron-and-anacron

**E para mais informações do Anacron acesse :**

http://anacron.sourceforge.net/

**Para monitorar a hora do desligamento de um Servidor Linux :**

https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Monitorando-hora-de-desligamento-de-servidores-Linux

**Para saber se seu Cron esta sendo executado normalmente :**

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/cron-jobs/did-cron-job-run