# Cron no linux minuto e dia da semana

Tags: php, javascript, ubuntu, linux

Gostaria de uma força com um Cronjob do Linux.

Segue:

```
*/1 * * * * wget http://192.168.6.80/sistema.php
```

Gostaria que esse processo fosse rodado a cada minuto, de segunda à sexta, de 18 às 06 horas da manhã.

Comment: Relacionado: [Configurar Cronjob para executar de 5 em 5 minutos, quando estiver dentre 5 a 20 horas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124518/configurar-cronjob-para-executar-de-5-em-5-minutos-quando-estiver-dentre-5-a-20)

Comment: Relacionado: [O que acontece com um Cronjob de 2:30, se o servidor cair às 2:28 e só voltar 5 minutos depois?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126422/o-que-acontece-com-um-cronjob-de-230-se-o-servidor-cair-%C3%A0s-228-e-s%C3%B3-voltar-5)

Answer (score 1):

O que precisa:

```
* 18,0-6 * * 1-5 wget http://192.168.6.80/sistema.php
```

O `Cron` faz a leitura de todos os arquivos e verifica se o momento atual é compatível com o `range` indicado no `txt`. Nesse caso:

```
*      //Cada minuto
18,0-6 //Das 18:00 às 23:59 e 00:00 às 06:00 
*      //Cada dia do mês
*      //Cada mês
1-5    //De segunda a sexta
```